# padding-top for display:table-cell

Tags: css

Here is the live link:
http://whiterootmedia.com/test/test8/

I need to move the menu content down in the "content" div. Here's the opening tag with inline css:

```
<div id="content" style="padding-top:43px; border:solid yellow 1px;  display:table-cell; min-width:945px; height:100%;">
```

If I increase the padding it moves down the content in the "right_column" div.

Answer (score 29):

The reason is that the two `div` elements are (in CSS sense) cells of the same row. When you increase the height of one cell, the height of the other cell increases, too. Its contents falls down, because the default `vertical-align` in table cells is `middle`.

To fix this, add the following:

```
#right_column {
  padding-top: 43px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```